# Serializing floating point number

Tags: serialization, floating-point, floating-point-precision

I was searching couple of forums to get some ideas on how to serialize floating point numbers and I happen to come across the following code.

```
oxdrstream&
oxdrstream::operator<<(
    float               source )
{
    BytePutter          dest( *this ) ;
    bool                isNeg = source < 0 ;
    if ( isNeg ) {
        source = - source ;
    }
    int                 exp ;
    if ( source == 0.0 ) {
        exp = 0 ;
    } else {
        source = ldexp( frexp( source, &exp ), 24 ) ;
        exp += 126 ;
    }
    uint32_t            mant = source ;
    dest.put( (isNeg ? 0x80 : 0x00) | exp >> 1 ) ;
    dest.put( ((exp << 7) & 0x80) | ((mant >> 16) & 0x7F) ) ;
    dest.put( mant >> 8 ) ;
    dest.put( mant      ) ;
    return *this ;
}
```

I don't understand why we need to do this

```
source = ldexp( frexp( source, &exp ), 24 ) ;
```

frexp() would return a value between 0.5 ( inclusive ) and 1 ( exclusive ).

For Eg:
 frexp() returns 0.81

ldexp( 0.81, 24 ) --> 19.44 and when assigned to unit_32 it's going to betruncated.

I dont see the logic behind this. Can someone clarify this for me ?

Answer (score 2):

`ldexp(.81f, 24)` does not produce 19.44; it produces 13589545. The code is designed so that the ldexp always produces an integer less than 2<sup>24</sup> and captures the significand exactly in `mant` (which ought to be called `significand`, because it is not a mantissa).

This code does not work for negative zero, subnormals, infinities, or NaNs.

Comment: I don't know why on earth I wrote 19.44. ldexp( x, y ) -> x * 2^y . In this case, it returns 13589544.96 rounded off to 13589545.

0.810000001 * ( 1 << 24 ) would return the same value, right ? In this case aren't we introducing additional precision loss ?

Comment: But ya, I did get the point you tried to make. Appreciate it !

Comment: The input is a float. Your “.81” is a double. The float input values will never have significands with more than 24 bits. When scaled as this code does, the result is always exactly an integer.

Comment: 24 bit = 23 bit mantissa + 1 ( in case of normalized number ). Is this what you mean ?

Comment: Yes. The parameter to this function is `float source`. If `float` is the 32-bit IEEE 754 binary floating-point format, then the result of the `ldexp` call in this code is always exactly an integer, and converting it to a `uint32_t` is exact; there is no change from truncation or rounding.

Comment: Aha I get your point.. Took a while to visualize mathematically.

x * 2^24 is what we are trying to do. x can be represented in 23 bit mantissa as follows

A = y*2^(-1) + y*2^(-2) + ... y^2(-23 ) where y is 0 or 1.
When multiplied by 2^24 we get the following

A * 2^ 24 = y*2^23 + y * 2^22 + ... y^(1) 
which should be a whole number.

Eric appreciate your help.